# Is my concern about this proposed statistical procedure correct?

Tags: regression, time-series

I am a mathematician that mostly narrowed in on logic when I was in school and have found myself working for a biology lab (long story) doing some data analysis. Recently, I have been asked to perform an analysis on some data that I feel is incorrect, but I am not sure, can anyone confirm or deny if my reasoning is correct? Here is the the situation:

There are these things called [OTUs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_taxonomic_unit). They are tables that have a few different common formats, but the one I am dealing  with works as follows:

1. The columns are samples. (so for instance, it could be a particular collection of dirt.)
2. The rows are the "relative abundance" of a particular microbe. (The term "relative abundance" is not too important for discussion, it can just be thought of as "count").

So, for example, a small table may be:

```
ID     1     2
       32   34   Ecoli
       64   60   Salmonella
```

This is read as: The soil sample 1 "had" 32 Ecoli bacteria, and 64 Salmonella bacteria in it. The soil sample 2 "had" 34 Ecoli and 60 Salmonella in it.

One common question to ask is are two bacteria correlated. For instance, if Ecoli population shoots up (dies off) does Salmonella shoot up (die off) with it (positive correlation)? Or, alternatively, if Ecoli population shoots up (dies off) does Salmonella die off (shoot up) in response (negative correlation)?

Usually there are a few tools for this that perform some transform on the data, and then apply a linear regression to the transformed data. For instance SparCC will give you in the end a matrix of r-values and p-values. To illustrate, here is an r-value table:

```
               Ecoli   Salmonella
Ecoli          1.0           -0.9
Salmonella    -0.9           1.0
```

Any bacteria is positively correlated with itself. Furthermore, in this case, if Ecoli population increases, we would expect Salmonella to decrease.

Now, I have a particular OTU where the time the samples were taken is known. Say, some person dug up some soil samples on day 1, day 2, and day 3. Of course, correlation does not imply causation, but strong correlations give a good reason to study later to see if there is actually some interesting mechanism governing the relation. The PI in the lab has suggest that a pair of microbes is a better candidate for study if a correlation remains for several days. The idea is to take an OTU and split it up into sub-OTUs that have only samples from that time point. Run some correlation software on each sub-OTU, this gives an r-value and p-value matrix for each day. The next goal is to filter out any pair that don't preserve the correlation across each day.

My implementation of this idea is as follows: consider we have Ecoli and Salmonella and two r-value tables and two p-value tables. Only consider entries with a high enough p-value as they are the only ones considered significant. If, for example day one Ecoli and Salmonella have a correlation of 0.9 on day one and -0.9 on day two, the correlation flipped too much, and Salmonella and Ecoli should not be considered for further study. If on the other hand, it was 0.9 on both days, the correlation remained and they should be considered for further study.

Here is my issue with this idea: Currently the standard way is to have a massive OTU and not consider time. The p-values are then computed and filtered based on that. From my understanding [SparCC](https://bitbucket.org/yonatanf/sparcc), for instance, calculates p-values through bootstrapping. Bootstrapping decreases in effectiveness when the data size is decreased. Furthermore, r-value is not a sensitive enough descriptor. My understanding is that bootstrapping fits a model to multiple random sub-samples and compares the actual coefficients of a particular model. So for instance, you may have a linear model of $a_1 x + b_1$ for one random sub-sample and $a_2 x + b_2$ for another. They may both have a positive r-value of 0.9 but a wildly different x-intercept which would cause it to pass the proposed analysis but fail the standard analysis.

My suspicion is that I should instead rewrite the algorithms to do bootstrapping on special subsets of the data based on the time. This becomes far more complex than what is being suggested. If I am wrong about my interpretation and this method is fine, it is a lot easier for me to implement.

Is my interpretation correct? Is my concern valid? Are there any other problems?

Comment: 1. '*it can just be thought of as "count"*' -- it might actually matter whether or not its *actually* a count or something else (like a scaled count say - that distinction can be important in many situations). Please don't assume some distinction is unimportant to how the statistics works and abstract it away unless you're *familiar with the consequences of doing so*. Better to explain the actual situation and let us figure out whether it matters whether it's a count or something else. 2. Counts are unlikely to be linearly related, especially where the correlation is negative. ... ctd

Comment: ctd... which implies that Pearson correlations may not be a good way of describing relationships for this problem. Note, for example, that a  negative linear relation implies that for large enough values of one variable, the other will be negative -- not possible for counts. Consequently the slope can't remain constant as the values on one variable or the other get close to zero.  3. There's not enough detail here that I can figure out what's going on; for example I find your third-last paragraph particularly unclear. 4. The bit about flipping correlation is particularly concerning; ... ctd

Comment: ctd... it suggests to me that there are some critically important sources of variation that are unaccounted for, and *any* attempt to come to conclusions about relationships is likely doomed without some clear idea of what the heck is going on there. I don't see how we can arrive at reasonable models on the present information .... I expect some of my confusions about what you're asking will be shared by others on site.

Comment: @Glen_b 1. Very sorry, I was trying to avoid dragging out the OTU discussion: It is a normalized count. The way it was explained to me: Sample 1 may have only 100 bacteria found (30 ecoli, 60 salmonella) and sample 2 may have 1000 found (333 ecoli and 667 salmonella). In the end the relative abundance for sample 1 will remain the same, for sample 2 it will be 33 and 67. Perason's does not work in general. 2. The [SparCC paper](https://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1002687) explains that many methods ((including Pearson correlation) do not work. ...ctd

Comment: @Glen_b It is currently an "open problem", SparCC is a possible solution. 3. By "third-last paragraph" do you mean the one that starts with "Here is my issue with this idea:"? 4. Unfortunately, I am not sure that there is a particularly reasonable model. I have been somewhat blindly using SparCC. It is tool that gives possible candidates for further study. My major concern is that I think the idea of eliminating candidates through changes r-value over time is a bad idea. It could be, however, that SparCC is a bad idea as well. I went under another false assumption and assumed it was ...ctd

Comment: @Glen_b fine. There may be too many issues in the model for cross validated to be of help. My lack of experience in statistics seems to be causing an issue with my communication.